# VB.NET Access to the path is denied

Tags: vb.net, file-io

NET to create folder

I would like to create folder to save data and 
I would like to copy these data to other folder.
However, whenever, I try to create folder and generate files 
I am getting Access to the path "path" is denied error

I tried to disable read-only option on the folder but it didn't work

I tried this way but it didn't work.

Save folder it under the folder in the Program Files
and I am copying data to "C:RESULT"

however, it doesn't work .. i am not sure why....

can you help me how to create folder and copy data to new folder?

> ```
> Private Sub createTimedFolder()
>     Dim folder As String = Now.ToString("MM_dd_yyyy_hh_mm_ss")
>     G_Folder = folder
>     '  MsgBox(folder)
>     If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(folder)) Then
>         System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folder)
>
>     Else
>
>     End If
>     ' MsgBox(folder & " created ")
>     Try
>         'Set the current directory.
>         Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(Path.Combine(defaultDir, folder))
>     Catch e As DirectoryNotFoundException
>         Console.WriteLine("The specified directory does not exist. {0}", e)
>     End Try
>
>
>     Dim LogBook = folder & "log.txt"
>     logwriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter(LogBook)
> End Sub
> ```

Comment: It looks to me like you are not specifying the full path when creating the directory, just the folder name. Are you sure it is not creating the directory somewhere where you are not expecting it? Have you trie searching your harddisk to make sure it hasn't created it where you didn't look?

Comment: Yeah, doesn't look like a complete path. There could also be a permissions issue. Would you consider saving it to the user's documents folder? Better practice than saving to root. Let me know if you want to save to user docs

Comment: I was thnking permission issue. When I was testing with other laptop, it was working file. but not this laptop. Funny think is, i can create folder with unix command

Comment: Are you running your application with full admin rights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here try this don't forget the Imports.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports System.IO
    Private Sub CreateTimedFloder()
            'You may change C:\ to the location of the folder that 
            'you want to create.
            Dim Directory As String = "C:\" & DateTime.Now.ToString("MM_dd_yyyy") & "_" & DateTime.Now.ToString("hh_mm_ss")
            Dim CompletePath As String = Directory & "\"

            If Dir(Directory, vbDirectory) = "" Then
                MkDir(Directory)
            End If

            Dim LogBook = File.Create(CompletePath & "Log.txt")
            Dim logwriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(LogBook)

            logwriter.Write("hello")
            logwriter.Close()

        End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to give permission (Read,write for User) for particular directory.
for example If You are creating directory in your application than you have to set permission on your application (Read,write)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the first few lines of code you create the temp directory.  This will be created relative to the execution path of the program.  In my test it created it in the /bin/Debug/ folder.

Then you try change to the default direct and the temp folder name.  The folder was not created under this default directory so that is where the error comes from.

You need to combine the defaultDir with the temp dir before creating the directory

```
    Private Sub createTimedFolder()
    Dim folder As String = Now.ToString("MM_dd_yyyy_hh_mm_ss")
    Dim CompletePath As String = Path.Combine(defaultDir, folder)

    Dim G_Folder As String = CompletePath
    '  MsgBox(folder)
    If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(CompletePath)) Then
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(CompletePath)

    Else

    End If
    ' MsgBox(folder & " created ")

    Try
        'Set the current directory.
        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(CompletePath)
    Catch e As DirectoryNotFoundException
        Console.WriteLine("The specified directory does not exist. {0}", e)
    End Try


    Dim LogBook = folder & "log.txt"
    Dim logwriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(LogBook)

    logwriter.Write("hello")
    logwriter.Close()
```

Comment: It still doesn't work :(. If I ran software with VB 2012, then it is working but if i made installpackage and run sw, then It gives access error :(

Comment: What is the exact error and which line is throwing it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this routine:
' Recursive function which keeps moving down the directory tree until a given depth.

```
Public Sub GetFiles(ByVal strFileFilter As String, ByVal strDirectory _
          As String, ByVal intDepthLimit As Integer, ByVal intCurrentDepth As Integer)

            Try
                Dim folderInfo As New DirectoryInfo(strDirectory)

                ' Is the current depth on this recursion less than our limit?
                ' If so, find any directories and get into them by calling GetFiles recursively (incrementing depth count)
                If intCurrentDepth < intDepthLimit Then
                    Dim directories() As DirectoryInfo
                    directories = folderInfo.GetDirectories()

                    For Each fDirectory In directories
                        ' Recursively call ourselves incrementing the depth using the given folder path.
                        GetFiles(strFileFilter, fDirectory.FullName, intDepthLimit, intCurrentDepth + 1)
                    Next
                End If

               
                Dim files() As FileInfo
                files = folderInfo.GetFiles(strFileFilter)

                For Each fFile In files
                    listView1.Items.Add(fFile.FullName)
                Next
            Catch ex As Exception
              
            End Try
        End Sub
```

Then you have to launch it this way:
Example: GetFiles("*.txt", "C:\Docu", 1, 0)

Comment: great code @giovannigiorgio! I played around a bit to gain more flexibility going deeper into the folder hierarchy. So, I added a numericupdown to manually increase  folder depth (i.e. '1' in your code) then added input textboxes to add main folder path and search term/extension at runtime. Now, increasing folder depth and watching file  count reveals maximum depth (i.e. file count no longer increases) and I now have a full list of files from main folder's subfolders! Brilliant! Thanks a lot! Is there a way to automate maximum folder depth for a specific file? E.g. *.txt in Documents?